# Как оформлять атрибуцию?

Tags: пунктуация, диалог, несобственно-прямая-речь

Уважаемые знатоки русского языка! Нет ли у вас ссылки на надежный и подробный свод правил по пунктуационному оформлению сложной атрибуции в диалоге и несобственно-прямой речи? (Розенталя, Валгиной и Лопатина уже не хватает!)